# Should downvotes no longer be anonymous?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Downvotes are currently anonymous on Stack Overflow. I've not received many, but the two or three I can remember are usually on a question or answer that has significantly more up votes and in the case of a question been favourited.

I'm not against downvotes, and I'm not so arrogant to believe that my posts can't be improved, but what help is a downvote without some kind of explanation? The downvote doesn't really bother me, but I would like to know why.

I wonder if it were possible to see who had downvoted if people would downvote more sensibly? Maybe leaving a reason is too complicated or time consuming, but if people could see who downvoted they might be more inclined to only downvote truly bad content and/or leave feedback?

Ultimately this is about using the downvotes to drive up the quality.

Comment: haha didn't take long for the ironic down vote without any feedback!

Comment: `Ultimately this is about using the down votes to drive up the quality.` Then why are you trying to make it about the user, and not the content itself?

Comment: The vote was neither ironic, nor without feedback (not that feedback is in any way necessary).

Comment: Because I think people would use their down votes more responsibly if it wasn't anonymous. An anonymous down vote helps no one.

Comment: Would an upvote mean yes, they should be anonymous? or yes i like the idea presented in the question.

Comment: @BenThurley Anonymous downvotes help lots of people.  If downvotes weren't anonymous then people would be less likely to actually downvote content that they thought was bad, making the site much worse.  It's already hard enough as it is to get people to downvote content that they know is bad, resulting in lots of bad content improperly marked as good content.  This would only exacerbate that problem.

Comment: Good point, I've changed the title. An up vote would mean yes they should not be anonymous now.

Comment: It's not just my posts. I regularly see down votes on content that is actually really good and has many up votes. This looks like tactical down voting. Maybe to make their own post rank higher? I don't know.

Comment: "they might be more inclined to only down vote truly bad content" What makes you think that people aren't being honest with their downvotes?

Comment: *"This looks like tactical down voting."* Data, please?

Comment: @BenThurley So you're saying that anyone who disagrees with you must be wrong, and couldn't possibly just have a different opinion of a post than you?  Sorry, but no, just because someone else thinks a post isn't helpful when you do doesn't mean that they're automatically wrong.  I don't assume that everyone who updates clearly wrong/unhelpful content is being malicious, after all.

Comment: There is little incentive to spend extra time on bad questions by giving explanations for downvotes.  Comments like 'Your code is a total pile of trash', 'Is your debugger broken, did you just not bother to do any because you expect the SO slaves to do it for you, or have you done some debugging but could not be bothered to tell us so we could all repeat it in parallel?' just get me flagged, then suspended.  Many posters cannot handle the truth, so it must be kept from them.

Comment: @Servy Not at all but I see your point. I thought down votes were meant for truly awful content, hence the voter losing rep points. We've all seen those questions that quickly get closed because they're so bad. What you're telling me is that down votes aren't so serious and people should use them liberally whenever they disagree with something. That's fine but I didn't think that was what they were for.

Comment: If I downvoted answers that were bad, both because they were intrinsicaly bad or because they answered bad questions, I would very soon have no rep left.  I very rarely downvote answers, restricting it to those that are totally and competely incorrect, (and often accepted:).

Comment: @MartinJames I saw something very sad the other day in the C tag though where a very high-rep user answered a very poorly-received question. I felt the same kind of temptation to down-vote there to punish the behavior, except it already had two down-votes along with a comment requesting, "Could someone explain why this was down-voted?" only to be met by silence. I ended up up-voting it out of pity, since it was a correct answer.

Comment: I've just checked the help page and I can't see an explanation on what down votes were for. My feeling was always that they were intended to be reserved for serious flaws. It's possible to see who votes to close a question so if down votes are equally severe it doesn't seem that crazy to me.

Comment: @MartinJames I tend to hate VLQs and want to see the interesting content as much as anyone else, but it was sad to me to see someone sincere and earnest in their answer being left hanging in the dust while wondering what they did wrong. I want to suggest an opposite route of this question -- extend the anonymity further by allowing anonymous, optional commenting in the context of a down-vote -- encourage people to explain why they did it without fear of retribution.

Comment: If you see that again, don't just upvote the correct answer, @Ike - try to fix the question too. Folks often forget that the question they're answering serves as essentially the introduction to their work - making that introduction look *good* is extremely helpful in making the work shine.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, that one question was beyond hope. I edited the formatting of it but it got down-voted to death -- it wasn't OT but it was just so, so, so hopelessly lacking in understanding that everyone reading it would probably get a, "Where do I even begin correcting these misunderstandings?" response. Except the answers managed to actually do it by breaking down the code behavior in a very beginner-friendly form.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, here is the question. But the down-votes are no longer there, possibly due to my intervention (interference?). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313553/does-setting-a-variable-equal-to-a-decrementing-variable-change-all-values-of-th

Comment: Oh lol, THAT question.. I left it alone.  I kinda hoped it was some sort of wnter bash hat troll, rather than a serious question:)

Comment: @MartinJames I can't tell since it was posed by such a low-rep user. But if we look at it, a lot of students posing so many of those Qs in tags like C are actually not far above this level of understanding. They're just masking it better with a "What's wrong with my code?" kind of question instead of a "What does this code actually do?" one.... so as pathetic as this question is, I actually don't see it as bad as some of the "fix my code plz" ones, since the answers give cooler, more educational explanations than a debugging service.

Comment: @Ike it's just a shame that it takes so much effort to find the thinnest of silver linings:(

Comment: The duplicate question didn't really help me. What did answer this question was the resulting discussion where people basically said they down vote as freely as they fart and they don't need a good reason. I think it should be made clearer perhaps because the implication with the voter losing rep is that it should be reserved for serious flaws and not just differences of opinion.... IMHO.

Comment: @BenThurley Tricky part is that, and it might vary by tags, we can get so many VLQs that it might be difficult to try to provide constructive criticism with every down-vote. I also see retribution a lot when people do actually give constructive criticism where, say, a student lashes out and says, "Dude, it's 2am, just help me fix my code!!!" (that's for Qs though). They lash out at the first person who comments and tries to be helpful. That's why I think we need anonymous comments or something of the sort for these cases.

Comment: Sadly, wherever I see 'it's 2am, just help me fix my code!', or the like, I now suspect that the poster is totally clueless, is unable to fix 'their code' and is just making money selling SO homework answers to other students. They do, indeed, get an immediate, anonymous down and close vote.

Comment: @BenThurley I think what Shog9 was describing (humorously) was just the nature of the community. We can't control how people use their votes -- they could vote you down just because they don't like your hat. Some down-votes might actually be genuine misclicks. I think the anonymity there is essential for what makes SO work. But the angle I think we should focus on is how to encourage more constructive feedback (probably best if it's also anonymous as with the vote) when people feel tempted to do it.

Comment: Should they be allowed to down vote because they don't like my hat? That would be a poor reason and doesn't help the site. I think if you're willing to put your name to a down vote then it would encourage against such frivolous down votes but I can see the appeal of a secret ballot. So in the end we just have to accept that some votes may not make sense or help much.

Comment: @BenThurley The site does empower ordinary people to determine the content of the site, and power in the hands of so many ordinary people will tend to get abused from time to time. But there are legitimate cases to keep down-voting anonymous (that would be an illegitimate example, but I'm just pointing out that it might exist). I agree with your rationale because I'm usually answering far more often than asking questions, and I see even answering to be a possibly-valuable educational process if someone corrects me or makes a suggestion. So I want to see the site encourage that more.

Comment: @BenThurley No, that would not prevent such downvotes, it *might* reduce their frequency a bit (although not necessarily) but that would only be by descrouraging people form downvoting *at all* for *any* reason.  It would also *increase* the amount of revenge downvotes that you see (because people would *know* who's voting on their posts), often resulting in cycles, potentially increasing the number of unconstructive votes *dramatically*.  It would also prevent *lots* of extremely helpful downvotes from people who really do feel that the post is bad, but are just trying to avoid revenge votes.

Comment: @BenThurley ... but I still think the anonymity behind voting is absolutely essential. Voting without anonymity works better for cases like Facebook since FB only allows likes, not dislikes. Down-votes lacking anonymity would often be a recipe for disputes and grudges (FB doesn't care about filtering away poor content).

Comment: Ok, so my suggested fix was a bad one. Fine. But it sounds like the problem is at least recognised. It's not just me being sensitive. Often I notice this on other peoples questions and answers too. So perhaps the question should be what would make people down vote more responsibly? Or maybe nobody really cares?

Comment: @BenThurley I tend to care a whole lot! And I think that's a good way to put it -- how can we encourage people to down-vote more responsibility, and provide constructive feedback when they do it? To me there's this angle of improving the quality of the site as a whole. We improve as a whole, and faster, when we get more feedback pointing out the issues people find with our content. I would just add that anonymity here is probably essential. Also don't worry about meta down-votes -- they don't affect rep or anything. I tend to see it as useful to measure how other people feel about a subject.

Comment: @BenThurley It's generally recognized that there are people that don't vote constructively.  It's also generally recognized that it's not a serious problem, because it's quite rare.  It's also generally recognized that anything that you'd try to do to restrict the freedom of voting would cause more harm than the very rare troll who votes on something other than the usefulness of the post.  So if you figure out how to invent a mind reading device that can prohibit people from voting maliciously without impacting those voting appropriately, then great, but short of that...

Comment: @Ike You're taking for granted that it's beneficial for people to post detailed information when voting, instead of just voting.  That's a false premise.  It's quite often (but of course not always) best for the site to just vote without providing any additional information.

Comment: @Servy One issue I'd point out is that it might be getting a little more serious. I'm seeing a lot of votes where the quality of the answer and question are being judged in a more tightly-coupled way, like that link I posted above. Some people are utilizing their votes to try to punish behavior they find disagreeable, like providing a decent answer to a poor question. About this premise, the way I'm looking at the site is more from a human perspective of users rather than the value of the information. Valuable information comes from users who understand what that means...

Comment: @Servy ... we train them faster if the site has ways to encourage providing that feedback in a way that doesn't lead to endless conflicts and disputes, and in doing so, improve the odds of the site generating better content sooner.

Comment: But the quality of a question and it's answer *are* coupled.  When a question is extremely bad it *does* impact the usefulness of the answer, so it's *correct* to take it into consideration in many cases.  The fact that you're going out of your way to reward people for providing content that's not useful, and incentivicing them to continue providing more content that's not useful, *is actively harming the site*.

Comment: @Ike The best way to avoid conflicts and disputes is to do nothing but vote.  The moment you comment in any way the odds of conflict/disputes raise *dramatically*, regardless of how constructive the comment is.

Comment: @Servy That's a very good point -- I tend to see it as possible to redeem a poorly received question with a good enough answer, but that might be a wrong way to look at things from a posterity angle. But even then, if we decide that down-voting a high rep user providing an excellent answer to a poor question is the right course of action, they would understand why they shouldn't be doing this sooner if we could explain this to them without the fear associated with a lack of anonymity.

Comment: @Ike It's not universally right to always downvote all answers to questions just because they're poor, but keep in mind that questions are considered bad, and get downvotes, precicely because they don't lead to quality content.  It's also a frequent mistake to assume that just because an answer contains correct information that it is a good answer, or that it's useful.  If the answer contains factually correct information but doesn't answer the question (say, because it's entirely unclear what the question is even asking) then it's not a correct answer to that question.

Comment: @Ike Likewise, if a question is extremely broad an answer could contain factually correct information, but still be woefully incomplete (as is virtually certain to be the case if the question is Too Broad), meaning that it's not answering the question.  If the question is offtopic, then even if the answer is useful, it's highly unlikely to be found by those it's relevant to (as it's in the wrong place), etc.  The things that make questions bad are, by definition, things that make the content of answers posted to them unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: @Servy Ah yes, but this example for instance is factually correct and does address the author's concerns quite well, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313553/does-setting-a-variable-equal-to-a-decrementing-variable-change-all-values-of-th. That said it might still be junk for the site because of the horrible Q which is so beginner-level that the better answer might be to read a book as indicated in the comments. But I'm seeing this from the perspective of, "How can we train the users on the site faster?"

Comment: @Ike That's the other issue.  It doesn't matter how useful the information in an answer is *if the people who need to find it can't find it when they're looking for it*.  So if the question isn't clearly asking for what the answer is providing, then it doesn't matter how correct, or well written, the information in the answer is, it won't actually be useful to people as they won't be able to find it, even if that same answer would help a ton of people if actually posted to a well written question that it is a complete answer for.

Comment: And of course, when people see a terrible question with a mediocre answer (even if it has no factual inaccuracies) it's frequently correct to downvote it, and they just aren't going to write 5 full comments explaining all of what I just said every time they do it, so people just assume that they're automatically downvoting all answers to any question with a negative score, even if that's not what they're doing.

Comment: @Servy I think we're very much aligned here in terms of what the most excellent content is for the site. But there's a dangerously broad area there where the most general questions on the minds of the world at large (which unfortunately consists mostly of beginners) can be quite general, and therefore borderline broad. BTW, do you mind going into chat mode? I imagine you're busy, but this is a very interesting subject to me.

Comment: @Ike Those broad topics simply aren't suited to an SO question.  Those topics are better covered in a book/class/tutorial/blog/etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98175/discussion-between-servy-and-ike).

Answer (score 44):

Y'know what's worse than endlessly debating a disagreement on some technical matter? **Endlessly debating whether or not being wrong on some technical matter is "bad enough to warrant a downvote".**

I don't want to discuss my votes. Votes are like flatulence; everyone does it, but you really don't need to call attention to it. If we're gonna talk about something, it should be the content of the post, not how folks voted on it.

There are... a bunch of other reasons to keep voting anonymous; search this site or [the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: +1 for flatulence even though I somewhat disagree (but agree here)! I do wish there was an *option* of some sort to provide an anonymous comment just in the context of down-voting. Some people might want to avoid potential retribution in suggesting a correction causing them to avoid down-voting and commenting (obviously not always, but even in rare scenarios, encouraging constructive feedback might help the site improve in quality as a whole and help everyone to learn the ropes faster).

Comment: The way I see it is that constructive feedback is a courtesy that should not be demanded/forced -- but some people might avoid it lacking anonymity merely out of fear of conflict.

Comment: @Luke, maybe not, but I bet you can smell it.

Comment: @Luke My vote is [silent but](http://aka.media.jibjab.com/assets/01/10/62/16/31ucx3.png)... oh never mind.

Comment: @davidism I call your *slightly disappointed* and raise you a *highly disappointed*.

Comment: I've been redirected to your post from one of my questions. If it's just a useless feature like you said, why does it take so much importance in SO? I guess votes are like money. When you have a lot you look down on people who don't. It's taboo to know how they get the money. They don't want you to know who gives the money or who steals it.

Comment: Voting is plenty useful, @gyc. Talking about votes isn't. There are many, many, many people who can vote - yet most of them don't, and those who do vote less than they should. Trying to shame folks into voting less seems like a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: The idea of anonymity is beautiful, until it's abused. If we can't talk about abuse, you're encouraging it.

Comment: Who said anything about abuse? You can talk about abuse.

Comment: What about people who downvote simply because they don't like your post, or you, or the fact the your question is not something they already know the answer to. Sometimes people on this site seem like they are just looking for easy points, when they see a post that seems like they should be able to answer but then can't, they just downvote. When it's more effort or complex to answer or requires significant setup, they downvote. Why? Because they wanted easy points and your question was a tease to them and now they are angry.

Comment: Some people downvote because they don't like the wording/phrasing of the question even when it means all the requirements layed out. Even if it lists the minimum code/ steps required to reproduce the issue and contains expected vs actual results.

Comment: Some people are searching for easy points and if they think they can get easy points of your question based on its tag and then find their expectations to be wrong, they downvote. Not for quality reasons, just because that's the level of person that they are. As it stands now I have not seen any efforts to address this kind of issue. The excuse is always given, there are more legitimate downvotes than not, and therefore curbing bad downvoting behavior could negativel impact good downvoting. As long as the downvotes aren't malicious (but are otherwise made in bad faith) the problem continues.

Comment: It happens, yes @Alexander. We know this because a lot of folks aren't shy about saying so. OTOH, it's relatively rare. The question is, why would we expect a loss of anonymity to change that? I suspect it is far more likely that we would simply see even less downvoting *across the board*, as everyone - including those voting in good faith - now has to fear petty retribution. Downvoting is already but a small fraction of all voting; reducing it further due to the actions of a few seems counterproductive. I would rather see effort put into encouraging *more* voting, up and down.

Comment: " The excuse is always given, there are more legitimate downvotes than not, and therefore curbing bad downvoting behavior could negativel impact good downvoting"

Comment: Can we not come up with some kind of compromise where people select a downvote reason from a dropdown, and the user sees the list of reasons and number of votes in each reason, but doesn't get to see who voted?

Comment: Why does it have to be all or nothing? Why do we have to choose between total anonymity and no feedback to the user and loss anonymity and feedback.  Is it really impossible to come up with a system where the question asker or answerer gets feedback anonymously?

Comment: There are several possible options there, @Alexander, although they would take a non-trivial amount of effort to be effective. Again though, I can't ignore the fact that voting *as a whole* has been kinda flat for years. Or to put it another way... It's far, far more likely that a post will get *no* votes than that it will get a downvote. Heck, no votes is more likely than getting an upvote. As much as I'd love to see the system improved, the first thing I'd want to see would be changes that... Just increased voting. Because otherwise... It's sorta wasted.

Comment: @Shog9 On the topic of not voting, there are a few good reasons. 1. Once a post is removed, one can't even see one's vote on it. That makes for manual logging of every vote and hence less incentive to actually do it. 2. The absolutely annoying instant popup on the voting buttons that makes some sane people shy away from ever getting their cursor close to those buttons. 3. The user interface on the reputation page doesn't allow for a separate view of deleted posts. It's all or just the non-deleted ones. 4. Fear of accidentally serial voting (now the logging comes in handy, but cumbersome).