# Are "Why the downvote?" comments ever automatically deleted?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags, deleted-comments

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180039/369434) [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179986/using-find-with-regex-to-find-a-file-name-that-begins-with-a-month-digit) yesterday. Another user happened to answer the same question at about the same time - our answers are very similar. Both our answers received a single downvote at the same time and no comments. There are currently no other answers.

About 7 hours ago I left two comments on my answer:

1. "Why the downvote?"
2. "How did you get on with this?" - Directed specifically at the OP

The first comment has since been deleted. There has been no comments / response from the OP.

Are "Why the downvote?"-type comments automatically removed? Are they removed automatically in response to a flag? Or do they still need to go through a manual moderation process? (Who/why deleted this comment?)

Comment: There are plenty of discussion on meta for/against downvoting answers to clear duplicate questions... The "regex for range of numbers" is not exactly uncommon question ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377926/regular-expression-numeric-range))... Also [tag:regex] was more *relaxed* than some other tags in that sense it may now have people subscribing to "downvote clear duplicates" camp.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "downvoting answers to clear duplicate questions" - Although in that case the question should be flagged as a duplicate and possibly downvoted? Here, the question was not flagged and was even upvoted!

Comment: MrWhite - putting your name out for *nice* comments by OP (as close votes are public) have very different bar than anonymously downvoting content that one thinks should not be posted... Note that all is pure speculation and votes could be regular revenge downvotes, tactical downvotes, "missed his key" downvotes or even simply for not providing complete answer (neither of 2 answers actually gives complete regex... and OP could downvote due to having 115 rep...)

Answer (score 28):

There is no automatic removal of "why the downvote?" comments (although there *should be*—read on).

The only comments that are automatically removed are the "Does this answer your question?" (used to be "possible duplicate of…") comments that are automatically generated on your behalf when voting to close a question as a duplicate. Those get automatically removed when a consensus is reached and the question is closed as a duplicate.

All other comments *must* be flagged in order to be removed. There are certain trigger words/patterns that will cause a comment to be instantly removed with only a single flag, like expletives. I'm not sure if "downvote" is one of those words/patterns, but I don't think it is. If a flagged comment isn't instantly removed, it will go into the moderator flag queue, where a moderator will review each comment and determine whether or not it should be deleted.

In almost every single case that a "Why the downvote?" comment is flagged, a moderator will agree that it needs to be deleted. **These comments are useless, and should never be posted in the first place.** Votes are anonymous, by design. [There is no system for users to provide an explanation to accompany their downvotes, and there will never be one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). You aren't supposed to comment on your votes, whether up or down. Furthermore, "Why the downvote?" comments are *especially* useless because it's almost certain that your intended audience will never see the comment. By the time you leave the inquiring comment, the downvoter(s) is/are long gone. If you *do* get a response to your comment, it'll be someone else saying something like, "Hmm, I don't know why your question was downvoted", and then either indicating that they do or don't agree with the downvote. All pointless. They should express their agreement or disagreement through votes of their own.

**Please do not post any more comments of the vein, "Why the downvote?", and do not post any more comments *discussing* votes in general.** These comments are inappropriate, and will continue to be removed on sight.

That is, in fact, what happened in [your case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180039/). You left a "Why the downvote?" comment below that answer, it was flagged by another community member as "no longer needed", and a moderator (who was not me) agreed with that flag and deleted the comment.

Speaking of pointless comments, you *also* left a "How did you get on with this?" comment below that same answer. I've deleted that comment now, as well, since it serves no purpose. If the asker wanted to provide feedback, they could do so either by leaving a comment, voting on the answer, and/or accepting it as the answer to their question. It is also their prerogative to choose to say/do nothing. Comments like "How did you get on with this?" just add noise.

Comment: Don't forget the *"Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer!"* comments :facepalm:

Comment: Or the, "Can you plz upvote my question?" comments. And don't forget the "Hope this helped!" comments.

Comment: @NickA Although when new users comment, "Thanks - works great!" and they fail to _accept_ the answer, I do find a "If this answered your question, then please mark it as accepted yardy yardy..." follow up comment to be very fruitful in most cases (shouldn't be necessary - but for some reason it is). (I always delete the comment later.)

Comment: @MrWhite then if there isn't more good than bad content, why do you think ppl should upvote more than they downvote? I personally think there is more bad content than good, so the votes should swing that way as well

Comment: So how are we supposed to get any type of feedback without having an explanation attached to the down-votes? Except for "you've been a bad boy", what can we possibly learn from a down-vote? Absolutely nothing. Not to mention the fact that many times user down-vote for no good reason other than condescending on new users. Pretty much every post gets down-voted these days and everyone thinks the system is fine and nothing needs fixing.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 Downvotes *never* mean "you've been a bad boy". They aren't an attack against you. Their meaning can be determined by reading the tooltip on the downvote arrow. They mean either that a question does not show any research effort, that it is unclear, or that it is not useful. For an answer, they mean either that the answer is unclear, not relevant, or technically incorrect. The system *is* fine. Downvotes don't have anything to do with condescension. They are a content rating system.

Comment: @CodyGray You're a mod with gzillion reputation points. As a low reputation user my experience is different. For example, recently I had a question down-voted (and voted for closure) by many people for "lack of effort" and received tons of condescending comments. I managed to solve my own question and ended up with a positive rating at the end after I started a meta post about the question. It has nothing to do with content quality and everything to do with shutting down new people. When more than 90% of the questions have negative scores than something is wrong.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 In the case of "condescending comments", please flag these for moderator attention. However, it is not surprising that a question would be downvoted for a lack of research effort; that is one of the normal downvoting reasons shown on the tooltip message. I'm glad that you were able to solve your own problem, but that doesn't make your claims true. Downvotes are *not* about shutting anyone down. They're about ranking content. That new users are less likely to post content that meets Stack Overflow's quality standards is a correlation, not causation.

Comment: Furthermore, it is absolutely false that "more than 90% of the questions have negative scores". The vast majority of questions have positive scores.

Comment: @CodyGray First of all, I demonstrated a lot of effort. It was just an excuse. This question was asked after several days of debugging and I mentioned it in the question. It was an excuse and there's no way around it. They couldn't provide a proper explanation as to why they are suggesting to close the question or why they down-vote. When I took this to meta people agreed with me and now the question has a positive score. Did the question magically become better? No, people were just being a-holes to low-reputation users like they always are.

Comment: I even provided examples of many similar questions with way less effort and way higher scores.

Second, you're right, I should have said "new questions". Granted, it could be that it's not 90% but 50%. It could be less than that, but from my impression, browsing through the tags I follow I see more questions with a negative score than the other way around. I really suggest you listen to new users and hear their experience. The vast majority will tell you that SO is awesome as a Q&A source, but the community is extremely rude and unwelcoming.

Comment: Stack Overflow has high quality standards. Posts that don't meet the community's quality standards get downvoted. That has nothing to do with being welcoming, @Pan. Votes are nothing more than how other users express their opinions regarding the clarity and usefulness of a post. I've posted many things that have been downvoted. The correlation you're perceiving between new users/low rep and downvotes just doesn't exist. I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55769904) with my "gazillion rep", and it still got downvoted because folks thought it was unclear. That's *fine*.

Comment: @CodyGray First of all I really appreciate the fact that you're addressing my comments about this issue. I know that sometimes down-votes are about the quality of the content, I'm saying that many times they are not. Regardless of the fact that there has to be a correlation between lower scores and lower reputation (even if I'm wrong), do you actually not believe that there are cases where users are getting down-voted for no good reason just because you personally are sometimes down-voted for good reasons? You're invited to check my profile for the mentioned post and judge for yourself

Comment: @Pan Aside from the correlation created by new users being unfamiliar with our quality standards (which are admittedly very high), I do *not* believe that there is any correlation between downvotes and rep levels/new users. I *definitely* don’t think “users are getting downvoted for no good reason”. Leaving aside vote fraud, which mods do handle, there’s always a good reason, usually related to the lack of clarity in the post or the lack of research effort. It might not be obvious to you, but it is well within the rights of the downvoters to express their opinion on the quality of the content.

Comment: The critical difference here is that I chose to interpret the downvotes on my question as being evidence that experts thought it was unclear and/or did not show sufficient research effort. I didn’t get mad about it, I didn’t start dismissing their judgments as without reason, I didn’t take it personally. I just took it as what it is: a signal. You, on the other hand, seem to start getting defensive about it, which doesn’t serve any purpose. I don’t have time to review all your posts. I don’t need to. The votes are a signal to you and future readers.

Comment: You're ignoring what I said. I never said that ALL down-votes are unjustified. I never said users don't have a right to down-vote. All I'm saying is that when I'm getting down-voted without any reason and then up-voted *for the same question* and see many similar questions (with less effort, btw) getting more upvotes than it's not about content quality. If you "don't need to" look at the evidence that what I'm saying is right than there's no point in continuing any discussion about it because you simply don't believe me which is your right.

Comment: @CodyGray _These comments are useless_ -- they may be useless, and may be not; that depends on wording and motivation a lot.
_Votes are anonymous, by design_ -- that is true, but commenting on votes is luckily not prohibited and should not be discouraged. And invitations to frank and grounded discussions should not be discourgared either.
In case discussions are discouraged, we all lose. We all lose mutual enrichment from exchange of opinions that just does not happen.
Do you agree? With all that in mind, do you still see reasons for requests for comments to be banned?

Comment: @SergeyUshakov Posts are already open to feedback by default. People are already free to provide feedback about the post at hand, but 1) you should not make it about the downvotes; 2) you should not pressure or shame people into providing feedback if they don't want to. As such, "why the downvote" is never worth asking.

Comment: @E_net4theidiotdownvoter My question was never about anything like pressure. Pressure should be discouraged anyway, this is true. My question/opinion is different. It is about free and friendly exchange of opinions for everyone's benefit. Why should such exchange of opinions be discouraged? Why should requests for opinions be discouraged?

Comment: @SergeyUshakov Maybe you should be reminded that this is not a discussion board, but a Q&A site. [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), so extended exchanges are correctly discouraged. Requests for discussion are noisy and not useful to future visitors. Even in practice, time and time again we see people getting insulted or harassed for showing up in a post from an unreasonable user (or otherwise just wasting their time as the post is not improved anyway), so your suggestion to let people request for feedback is also an invitation to laying abuse traps.

Comment: No, they're always useless, @Sergey. Wording and motivation don't matter at all. Commenting on votes *is* prohibited: you should not do it. Invitations to discussion are also prohibited, as this is not a site that allows discussions. We may be enriched by exchange of opinions, but this site is not the place for that. So, no, I do not agree. Requests for opinions are already explicitly *not allowed* on this site, so what you're arguing for is a complete *non sequitur*.

Comment: @mark It is also not nice [calling people names](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926751/mark) or [yelling at them](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77098326/2) when you don't get what you want. Think about it. You received **only one downvote** on a question. It does not imply malice or poor intentions, it was just one person's opinion. Regardless of the reason, you could have just shrugged it off as an off-by-one mistake. I did not downvote on it, but with that kind of attitude, one will be inclined to say that whoever did downvote was right to walk away without leaving a comment.

Comment: @E_net4 imho if you are going to downvote a question you should provide a reason why, that would complete the loop and provide feedback. The constant downvoting and closing questions as duplicates by mods (quite often when they are not) is why SO is loosing traffic. SO used to be a respected site; these days that is not the case and most professional engineers I know will only post a question as an absolute last resort as 9 times out of 10 they find a solution elsewhere.

Comment: @mark if one has valuable feedback to provide, they should provide it. If the post is low quality/unclear, they should downvote it. The two actions need not be related.

Comment: As a comment on this 3.5 years old answer: I have seen many times "why the downvote" comments answered by later users, saying "it wasn't me but it's possibly because of [this specific actionable issue]", similar to people asking about downvotes on meta. This is very useful, it doesn't matter that votes are anonymous or that the original downvoter is long gone. The OP wants to know what they did wrong, somebody gave them a detailed pointer instead of the generic downvote reason from the tooltip, and the site is better off for it.

Comment: @Marijn In that example, the site is not better off because they discussed why someone voted a certain way, but because they provided feedback on what could be wrong with the post. That is where the focus should be, [not on the downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312634).

Comment: @E_net4 sure, but the feedback on the post was prompted by the OP asking about the downvote, otherwise the feedback would not have been provided. Maybe downvotes (and discussion thereof) are the wrong focus, but that seems like arguing over semantic details ("why the downvote" is a paraphrase of "what is wrong with my post" imo) and it fails to acknowledge the central role of the downvote in starting the interaction and providing incentive to act on the feedback, i.e., possibly getting an upvote after the post is improved that counters the downvote, or preventing additional future downvotes.

Comment: @Marijn I'm afraid that none of that changes the facts that there are several known issues with pressing people to provide feedback when they downvote, and that it's established moderator policy to clean up "why the downvote" comments. If you want that policy to change, that would earn itself an independent Meta question.

Comment: @E_net4 protecting people from being "pressed" (although protection is not really needed, people can decide freely whether to engage or not) is not the argument that Cody Gray used in this answer on which I commented. His argument was that the comments are **useless** (emphasis his), as the downvoter will most likely not see them (again voiding the "being pressed" point, you can't be pressed if you don't notice the pressing) and voting is and should remain anonymous. My comment was that it is _not_ useless, as it leads to improved posts because of _other_ people explaining the downvote.

Comment: @Marijn Fine, it might not be entirely useless, but it it nevertheless not the good thing to do all the time, and still merits deletion as per the current moderation practices.