# New question downvoted and closed but simpler wording and better performance than duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I posted the question [More efficient list of all files in a directory in PHP, sorted by modifiation time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155330/more-efficient-list-of-all-files-in-a-directory-in-php-sorted-by-modifiation-ti)

I see now, that it is *nearly* a duplicate of [Sort function works wrong with filemtime PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653814/sort-function-works-wrong-with-filemtime-php), [How to sort files by date in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php), [Sort files with filemtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877807/sort-files-with-filemtime), [glob() - sort array of files by last modified datetime stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-array-of-files-by-last-modified-datetime-stamp). I say "nearly" because my post focuses on the speed performance aspect of doing it on thousands of files, which is not present on these linked questions.

I always see "close as duplicates" as something beneficial (and every now and then I close my own questions as duplicate of other ones) but, here, I see my question is -3 voted, nearly "deleted" (wouldn't "closed" be enough?), and I thought my question had some benefits:

- short self-contained question, with MCVE, easy to read wording
- short answer with working code, better speed-performance

whereas all the linked questions were:

- more complex to read: [How to sort files by date in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)
  Here the MCVE is mixing HTML tags and things that are not related to date-sorting
- or worse: [glob() - sort array of files by last modified datetime stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-array-of-files-by-last-modified-datetime-stamp)
  Indeed this question has no MCVE (not optimal in terms of SO standards), and the answer has very poor performance because it doesn't cache the mtimes.

I don't really care about this specific question, but **what to do in general when a new question is objectively better than old duplicates but receives a bad reception?** (whereas it's not *exactly* a duplicate, it is about performance improvement)

Comment: Your question was not closed as a duplicate, but as "Needs focus". Also you have just presented a problem without any attempt in solving that problem. It is really hard to qualify this question as "better" and as good example of the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar the history of this question for me is 1) write code which is not speed-efficient 2) post a question on SO, including this MCVE  3) receive feedback in comments 4) post a solution properly citing this feedback as source 5) I see my original non-efficient code is the answer of another question, I edit my question to cite it. So the attempt to solve my problem was my first code I wrote, before knowing what could cause the performance problem (thus the question).

Comment: "objectively" is a strong word. I understand you think your question is good. You need to be open to the idea others may not agree.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped what kind of effort people are expecting in the context of the question. *Any* question could be shot down with "well why don't you just do the thing that would do what you want". As the linked not-quite-dupes show, many people would not just do that thing.

Comment: Sorry, but your workflow is bad. There is no attempt in trying to solve your own problem between 1 and 2. I find it hard to believe that you couldn't figure out the rather trivial solution yourself. Yes, I know, sometimes obvious can be elusive enough. I also don't have problem with you posting answer yourself. But how on Earth have you come to the conclusion this is example of "good" question?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar There is a multitude of things that could have been responsible for the slow perf. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802499/1422096). `Year 2020 - If you care about performance, consider not to use glob()!`. It could have been this. But it's not. What I mean is that it is not a 100% trivial a priori, thus my original question.

Comment: @Basj I meant, you take all potential bottlenecks and investigate what is the real cause. Of course, at the end such research would probably end up in figuring out the real problem and solution yourself. After you do that and you cannot find appropriate Q/A here, then asking self answered question would be an option. And in that regard your question as such accompanied with much more elaborate answer comparing to one you wrote would be acceptable and could serve as helpful addition for other people.

Comment: So, it is not that your question is inherently that bad, but you are most likely being judged by higher standards because of your reputation and existing knowledge. Whether that is fair or not, is another question.

Answer (score 5):

> what to do in general when a new question is objectively better than old duplicates but receives a bad reception?

Just try to improve it within your capability. This includes listening to feedback and doing your best to apply it. [Refrain from](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393913/are-why-the-downvote-comments-ever-automatically-deleted) leaving "why the downvote" or "why the close vote" comments as well.

The key idea is the following: *if the question truly is objectively better, it won't be poorly received forever*. Give it time¹ and the votes will come. If that does not happen, then bad news: it isn't as good as you perceive it to be. Remember that the author of a post isn't the best person to make that assessment.

---

¹ This is more relevant than you might think. Those two linked questions are from 2008 and 2010. Not only were they posted at a different age of the platform when there were fewer questions, they also had much more time to accumulate votes organically.

Comment: A vote count of -4 seems like a very deep hole to dig out of. I would guess that many people won't even bother to look at the question when they see such a score. It likely won't matter if the question is actually good once there's enough mud sticking to it.

Comment: I generally agree with the "Give it time" aspect and I have observed it many times in the past years. But here, indeed -4 is a deep hole, and it will be roomba-ed and burnt into flames before anything can happen ;)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My observations in certain tags provide a different picture. If the question does not fulfill one of the reasons to be closed, and indeed becomes useful, then the chances are that it will step out of the negative. It's the whole point of the lifeboat badge too.

Comment: The question is at -5, closed, and has 2 delete votes right now. I'm not an SME, but TBH every single one of these is hard for me to understand.

Comment: _"If that does not happen, then bad news"_, @MisterMiyagi.

Answer (score 3):

> **new question is objectively better**

It is according to you. There have been more than 4 other people who thought otherwise.

I agree the reaction this post received is a little bit harsh. There's no need to immediately delete a question like this. The problem is many users just follow the mantra: if a closed question is not reopenable and has an accepted answer, it can be safely deleted. This is not the best approach as the question might still be salvaged by others.

In this case, I would probably agree that there's not much to salvage. Sorting an array with 2500 elements should be almost instantaneous, so it's clear that the problem is repetitive calls to filestat. As it usually is with such problems, the answer is to precompute the expensive operation. This is called **[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)**. It could have been a fetch from a database, an API call, or some other expensive operation. The solution is the same: cache the values in an array and then sort them. Sorting is never O(n) so precomputing values is the best option.

This question isn't useful, because we already have a generic solution for [sorting files by modification time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476123/1839439). As for the topic of memoization, your question isn't worded the best to direct people to your solution. I would dare to say that your question isn't unfocused, it's focused too much. There was [a similar question in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302719/php-usort-order-string-by-length-optimization) that suffers from the same issue. It's focused on a particular function and isn't easily searchable.

Comment: *"so it's clear that the problem is repetitive calls to filestat... the answer is to precompute the expensive operation."*: it's clear a posteriori, but it doesn't seem so clear because nobody is doing it [in all the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-array-of-files-by-last-modified-datetime-stamp) and it's not done [in the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-array-of-files-by-last-modified-datetime-stamp/60476123#60476123).

Comment: A posteriori it's easy, but not *a priori*: the slow perf could have come from something else: use something else than `glob` (see the other answer `Year 2020 - If you care about performance, consider not to use glob()!`), etc. But here not using `glob` wouldn't have changed anything. This was not the bottleneck. This shows it's not 100% trivial.

Comment: @Basj In general calling any function inside `usort` will be bad for performance. This is what I meant. There are no other elements to the puzzle, it's either the sort itself or the called function.

Comment: Yet in your question you mention "probably due to the thousands of calls to `filemtime`".  I think you had the solution already there, present in the question. Try to sort by something that didn't call `filemtime` and see the results, then the  answer becomes obvious. I understand, it happens. Many times we do not find an obvious answer until we ask the question aloud. Mighty Ducky to the rescue.

Comment: Haha yes @yivi, sometimes true!