# I think the question I closed as a duplicate shouldn't have been reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

The question is here: [Double Iteration in List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198777)

I had hammered it with what I consider canonical: [How can I use list comprehensions to process a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759)

The question seems to have been reopened (by vote) a few days after my closure. Specifically, it appears that OP requested to have it reopened, and then it got two "leave closed" votes and two "reopen" votes from review. I wasn't notified about the reopening (as I'm sure is normally the case).

I think it is the same question because, in the first case, OP wanted to perform fundamentally the same task: iterate over an input which is a nested list, using a "nested" list comprehension. I had been trying to establish the proposed duplicate as a *general technique* canonical - showing how to nest list comprehensions, choose the appropriate form of nesting for the problem, and then apply whatever transformation.

My refutation of the arguments against closure:

> "The other question is particularly about transforming elements in nested lists, this question is about internal dependencies of multiple iterators within list comprehensions."

The important thing when working with list comprehensions is the actual iteration. The "transforming elements" part simply meant calling `float` on each one as they're iterated over, which is not particularly interesting. More to the point, it seems absurd to say that "How do I use `float()` to convert each element in a nested list to float?" "How do I use `int()` to convert each element in a nested list to int?" etc. are separate questions. (In fact, for the case of a simple list, we already have [Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/), which in my mind is *still not broad enough* - a list comprehension can incorporate an expression in terms of the iteration variable, not just a function call.)

At any rate, understanding the "internal dependencies of multiple iterators" bit is **crucial to the problem regardless**, and thoroughly explained by the answers on the second question.

While it's true that the first question doesn't ask about *any* transformation, the capacity for transforming the elements is **inherent to** list comprehensions. They're unavoidable; in the case of the first question, we're simply specifying the identity transformation.

(Of note: we also have a much more established canonical about [flattening a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914) - which can be phrased as "iterating, performing no transformation and producing a flat result". However, there are other approaches to that problem besides list comprehensions, which may have performance or other advantages; both questions discussed here specifically asked about list comprehensions exclusively.)

> I don't know who closed this question as duplicate of another question that is 4 years younger than this. If at all the other question would be the duplicate.

It's well established that question age [is irrelevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938) here. I think the answers on the proposed duplicate are much more detailed and higher quality overall (I mean, just look at that beautiful animated GIF). The proposed duplicate focuses on the same interpretation of a "nested" list comprehension as in the first question (`[cell for row in grid for cell in row]`), but also describes the other reasonable interpretation (`[[cell for cell in row] for row in grid]`; note that a different order is necessary in order to make a nested result vs. a flat result). While this could be argued to represent a lack of focus, the question attracted excellent answers for both issues; and **someone with either problem might phrase it the same way** - I would prefer not to have people find the "wrong" version of the question by chance with Stack Overflow and then conclude that the "right" one isn't there.

Comment: This is ongoing, subtle resistance based on meaningless hairsplitting is why curation just sucks. \*sad, resigned face\*

Comment: I wouldn't even mind the resistance to identifying things as "duplicates" if Stack Overflow had a more sophisticated system for relating questions. Something that could classify "question X is a generalization of Y / Y is a special case of X", for example, or "X is an application of technique Y", etc. etc. and then automatically push useful links in the user's face.

Comment: Generally before hammering something with 300+ votes, I would recommend to open a meta discussion _before_ doing so, not afterwards. Ideally you should have a general consensus between multiple gold badgers (Python in this case) before closing. Also ideally, those who are partial having posted the question or an answer should refrain from moderating it by casting close/re-open votes, at least not without making an argument on meta first.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I hear that, but at the same time I fear people would just make a complete mess out of it. It is apparently already too hard to pick a proper matching close reason. So what happens when a close reason has close reasons of its own.

Answer (score 16):

I've gone ahead and directly dupe-hammered the question again.

Seriously, I am sick of having to go through what feels like a triple-blind quadruple-approved scientific review *when questions are obviously duplicates*. Reopening a duplicate is for fixing mistakes; it is not for beating off curation from ones own favourite question/answer.

A "nested iterable" and "double iteration" are *exactly the same* in a list comprehension. It matters zilch whether that is fed to a tuple expression, a `float` conversion, and whathaveyou.

Comment: To clarify, the question was voted to reopen, not un-hammered.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That ruins the pun but not the point. ;)

Comment: "*Reopening a duplicate is for fixing mistakes; it is not for beating off curation from ones own favourite question/answer*" Well, one can genuinely think it is not the same question. At the end of the day it sometimes just boils down to which group of voters is bigger/has more voting power.

Answer (score 2):

- While I might still think differently about the distinctness of two questions, I'm generally fine with other people's judgement that they are "close enough". (Users vote with their feet anyway.)
- I only looked at the other question, not the available answers, but, too, find that this is a good criterion to decide which question to choose.
- I was not aware that the age of the questions doesn't matter (having worked with other systems that try to identify duplicates).
- I was also not aware about discussing issues of specific questions on meta. But for this to be an interesting option the person closing the question should be linked in the Duplicate banner so I could engage them directly in the discussion.
- My question about the reasoning in a comment was a true question, not just resistance. It was in the same vein as people asking for explanation when their answer is down-voted. So re-closing it with a comment like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198777/double-iteration-in-list-comprehension#comment132777883_1198777) would have probably been fine with me.
- Ah, one other thing: The term "already" in the Duplicate banner is then misleading. Maybe it should say "better".

Comment: The tooltip for me says "(List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege)" and since you were able to reopen-vote you should already be able to see who voted. The banner should look like this to you: "This question already has answers here:
Comprehension on a nested iterables? (13 answers)
A community member has associated this post with a similar question.
**Closed 56 mins ago by MisterMiyagi** [tag:python].
(List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege)" Is this really not visible for you?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi only if the viewer is also not the OP of the question. Otherwise, they won't see the names on the banner regardless if they can vote to close/reopen.

Comment: Nope, but may I've lost this privilege :sweatsmile:. I don't get that tooltip, I don't see the voters either, and the banner text just says (apart from hinting at the possiblity to edit the question): "Find out more about duplicates and why your question has been closed. Closed 1 hour ago.". "duplicates" and "has been closed" are linked to general help topics, and "1 hour" has a tooltip, but it only shows the time stamp.

Comment: I once dupe hammered a question of mine. I still can't see who voted to close the question, even if it's myself and no one else. It's pretty stupid

Comment: What?! At 20k you should be able to see full data on who closed your question regardless of whether it is yours. And mods should regardless of reputation... that seems like a bug report that needs to be filed.

Comment: @TylerH, Close votes visible for everyone in the history (irrespective of post authorship, reputation or sign-in status). Most people are *incapable* (not the once's fault it just made look non-noticeable/non-clickable/non-self-explaining) seeing or clicking that icon. The only restriction is close voter names are not shown on the banner to OP.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know they're visible there. My point is that at 20k+ (and certainly upon election as a moderator by your peers) you have shown enough familiarity with the site, ostensibly, to know how to use/not use the information that's visible to everyone else. It's silly to hide the closer of your question from you when you have 20k/a mod diamond, and I'm sure it was either done inadvertently or simply left that way because it was _less work_ during implementation, not because there was a good reason to do it that way.

Comment: Close votes are visible from from 3k+, I suspect not being able to see voters on your post might be a bug relating to you not reviewing an item in the close votes queue before @ThomasH  however, that doesn't explain the issue that Zoe had with her post as she has definitely reviewed in that queue before

Comment: _" It was in the same vein as people asking for explanation when their answer is down-voted."_ [You should not be doing that either.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393914)