Why is this comment not unfriendly/unkind?
Two days ago I reported this comment as unfriendly/unkind:

Whoever downvoted my question, you really are a weird person. Downvoting with a comment as WHY downvoted makes sense so that I can at least fix the question or something. But anyways, good luck to you as a developer who only knows to find faults and no solutions.

My reasoning is that it starts off by calling the downvoter "really a weird person", which is not something you should call anyone in a professional environment; and is followed by unwarranted and excessively snarky remarks about their modus operandi as a user on Stack Overflow and as a developer in general.
However, my flag was declined, with the comment removed anyway. Why was that? Was this a mistake from the moderator? Why should we not advert people not to make inappropriate remarks such as these in the future?

Looks unfriendly/unkind to me.

This was not unkindness by accident, but by personality. The entitlement in that demonstrated ignorance of the site speaks volumes. You made the right choice.

The sentence "you really are a weird person" feels like it should tip this into the rude category... but on the other hand, I have previously written a (not only undeleted, but very highly upvoted!) comment addressed to someone I was frustrated with that started with the sentence "seriously, what's wrong with you?", which is equally explicitly insulting. The distinction, I guess, is that everyone reading my comment felt the exasperation was warranted... but should mods be adjudicating rudeness flags differently based on whether hostility is warranted or not? I dunno; maybe they should!

The last phrase "But anyways, good luck to you as a developer who only knows to find faults and no solutions." is also unkind, slighting the anonymous subject by saying they're no good at finding solutions.

@MarkAmery Warranted or not, that reply would be flag-worthy, as well.

@TylerH Perhaps it would, or perhaps not. I suggest a test of principle for you and others. Above is a comment by Gimby which accuses the subject of this Meta thread of "unkindness ... by personality", of "entitlement" and of "ignorance". It's framed explicitly as an attack on their character and not just a criticism of a particular comment - indeed I'd say it's a far harsher attack than calling someone a "weird person". Have you flagged it as rude? Has anyone? If not, aren't we accepting harsh personal insult because we think it's deserved? What does that mean for moderating rudeness?

Probably the best response to that comment is to point out that it's because of responses like that that few people explain downvotes and are recommended to not explain.

@MarkAmery I don't think there's any scenario where asking someone "what is wrong with you" is not classified as 'unfriendly/unkind'. At the very least such comments (and likely the entire thread) should be removed.

I'm going to cut off (and delete) the debate about the merits of leaving comments with downvotes here; that has been debated endlessly and we don't need yet another rehashing of that debate in the comments of this post.  Let's focus on the topic of whether comments like this are unfriendly/unkind (which may be the case regardless of whether downvoting without commenting is also unkind).

@MarkAmery I once earned myself a 2-day suspension after getting "exasperated" in just that sort of way a few times in a row. I have come around to the belief that we should, in fact, expect ourselves to rein that in. Copy-and-paste template comments help a lot with this IMX. (Sometimes they provoke actually rude responses; can't win 'em all.)

Unfriendly is a binary decision while there is probably a whole spectrum of more or less friendly or unfriendly comments out there. There will always be a gray zone. The important thing is that the comment got removed. That was the aim.

@user4581301 "it's because of responses like that that few people explain downvotes and are recommended to not explain." We don't know why people do not often explain downvotes. Could also be simply not wanting to spend time on that.

Mod note: Comments complaining about anonymous downvotes are not relevant to this question; please refrain from continuing to post them here. There are plenty of other discussions about this topic already. Please direct your comments there instead. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393913/6296561 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/6296561

Sorry if im being rude, but it really doesn't look unfriendly/unkind.. idk lol

@Truder Would you be fine with saying it to your boss?

@E_net4 yep. if he was being a "really weird person", sure , i would say the truth and call him that.

@Truder 1) In this case "really a weird person" was triggered by simply voting on a question, so that "if" might not even apply. 2) Since it was followed by petty denigration, "really weird person" wasn't the only insulting part of the comment. 3) You're fired.

@E_net4 ok, i guess I understand now.

@e_net out of curiosity did you downvote the post? Any reason why you would be so upset about a declined flag when the comment was deleted (which is what the end result should be)?

@SalmanA There's no need to make this about me in particular. I only found the comment and flagged it. Aside from the comment being deleted, there is some level of importance in flags being well handled for the reasons I already described below. The flag being declined was more negatively surprising than upsetting to me, so I figured I would seek clarification here.

@MarkAmery I've been thinking about the "seriously, what's wrong with you?" thing.  I think the difference there is that phrase has the idiomatic meaning of "Your behavior is out of line", and the "what's wrong with you" is treated primarily as being critical of the behavior. On the other hand "you really are a weird person" does not have a similar idiomatic usage and is immediately viewed as an attack on the personally of the person.

@M.Justin That's a valid take on my comment (though uglier readings are possible!). Gimby's, earlier in this thread, perhaps illustrates my point better. It is an unusually unambiguous personal attack, in that it goes out of its way to spell out explicitly that it is condemning the target's character and not merely a particular moment of misbehaviour. Yet 15 people (so far) have upvoted it and mods have not deleted it. How should we interpret this? It seems to me we collectively permit even such personal attacks as long as we think they're warranted. And maybe that's reasonable and fine?

@M.Justin [cont.] But if my interpretation above is right - that we are simply more permissive of unkind personal comments when we reckon the target deserved them - it's a reason to be a bit sympathetic to the commenter discussed in this question (who called someone else a "weird person"). Perhaps we are kidding ourselves if we think their core sin was being rude, and in reality it was being ignorant of the norms of our community and of when and against whom we accept rudeness. And for that, we will endorse a comment calling their personality "unkind", "entitled", and "ignorant". Hmm...

@MarkAmery — Maybe, but even without the rest of the context, I would interpret "seriously, what's wrong with you?" as meaning the person is being called out for doing something utterly unacceptable, whereas "you really are a weird person" is just mean and shaming someone just for being different.  The former is harsh but can be completely justified as refusing to tolerate unacceptable behavior.  The latter just comes across as mean and uninclusive.

@MarkAmery everyone reading my comment felt the exasperation was warranted it's an example why we never able to escape "opinion-based". Everything we do is technically opinion-based...

@MarkAmery I personally don't think it's a good idea to justify a possibly inflammatory comment on the basis that "that person deserved it". There's no way to draw a clear line on when it is acceptable™ and such action is more likely to trigger the person than actually having a calming effect. And if we were on Interpersonal Stack Exchange, I would go as far as saying it could have unintended consequences

I would say that more than 120 upvotes say more than one declination :-)

@Dominique More than 130 upvotes say foremost that bike-shedding is a real phenomenon and that hot questions attention can be misguiding peoples' attention. Of course there will always be different opinions on everything, but apart from this there is not much that could be added that would result in more clarity.

No one that use their votes should be called "really a weird person". Because they are not.
Such phrases go into the abusive behavior category of the Code of Conduct and should always be flagged.
We obviously can then have a debate whether this is red-flag material or no longer needed material. I will get very worried when the comment wouldn't have been deleted so I'm glad your flag at least has the desired outcome. I personally would have marked the flag as helpful because of the CoC violation but if the commentator is frustrated enough you might run in a declined flag.
That is frigging frustrating but here we are.
Please keep flagging that kind of comments, declined flags or not.

I will keep your insights in mind for the future. I am sometimes wondering whether I personally have too high tolerance, which then may get in a way of handling flags appropriately.

@DalijaPrasnikar I would keep the high tolerance because this is not kinder garten but when it comes to comment flags I would err on the side of the flagger. Specially when the comment needs to go anyway for other moderation reasons.

I understand that "not kindergarten" should mean that we allow bluntness (especially when it's telling people to do things that are in line with policy), but still not anything that insinuates bad motives, lack of cooperativeness etc.

Unfriendly? Yes. But not abusive. It isn't targeted at a known user. Weird just means out of the ordinary and unusual behavior and OP explained their reasoning for calling such behavior "weird" or unusual. Outside of Meta, no one believes just voting without commenting is rational and I don't think expressing such belief at a incognito voter is abusive by any stretch of standards.

@TheMaster It is abusive per application of the Abusive behavior policy. It would be bullying and harassment should it continue with follow-up comments. Hostile comments in any case, check. Denigration is also present. Moreover, your second statement is highly contestable. Where exactly is that decent and unbiased voting system where people are forced to comment alongside their vote?

@TheMaster You leave a comment with each and every one of your votes? I find that hard to believe.

@AzorAhai-him- When did I say I do that? I said it is rational to think "Adding a comment, when downvoting helps to improve the quality of the post".For the OP of that question to react the way they reacted, they must have valued the quality of the question they posted, they must have took the time and effort(T&E) to post.If it was just a garbage post, that OP didn't take T&E to make up, they wouldn't have cared at all. Also reading between the lines of mod Dalija, I believe they felt the vote was unjustified and therefore was able to empathize with the OP so much that they declined the flag.

@TheMaster reluctance to remove such content historically had a huge amount to do with the common negative off-site perception of Stack Overflow. A professional environment demands avoidance of anything that could be construed as an attack on a personal level, whether actually directed personally or aimed at a class of people or a vague referent like "whoever downvoted my question".

@KarlKnechtel OP needed direction to improve quality of the post. There seems to be at least one negative reaction to the post. But apparently the current system is not designed to show the reasoning for that reaction, which OP thinks would greatly help him to increase the quality of that post. I believe comments are temporary and can be used as a temporary bridge to address that deficiency. But it could've been done in a friendly manner.

@TheMaster "no one believes just voting without commenting is rational," This implies that voting without commenting is irrational, and I assume you don't do things you believe are irrational.

@AzorAhai-him- I didn't say I believe it. Did I? I'm inside Meta. That quote was  "Outside of Meta, no one believes just voting without commenting is rational,". I know how users interact outside Meta. And that's not a incorrect belief(that comments should accompany downvotes) in and of itself. If you were never exposed to Meta's beliefs and opinions,  it wasn't a irrational thought process. Even in meta,  users still argue for commenting, when downvoting. I've been outside meta, inside meta, for meta and against meta..

@E_net4 If you truly believed it was abusive, why didn't you use the "abuse" flag, but rather chose the "unfriendly" flag?

@TheMaster "abuse" has different meanings in different contexts, in the context of comment flags it means a comment that uses abusive language targeting a person or a group, etc. in the context that E_net4 is speaking about abuse means abuse of the platform (i.e. using the platform / site in a way considered bad) which is described further in the abusive behavior policy.

"weird" is definitely not abusive. According to different dictionaries it means something like "very strange and unusual, unexpected, or not natural". (this is from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weird).

@Stefan that is a very strange and unusual, unexpected, or not natural comment.

@Stefan Not everything unfriendly is explicitly listed as such in the dictionary. If you want a prime example of this, consider "idiot", defined as "a stupid person or someone who is behaving in a stupid way". It's not abusive in the right context (for example, you can call a decision idiotic without that being an attack on the person making it), but if you call someone else an idiot, that's still unfriendly. "weird" is similar; the word itself isn't necessarily unfriendly, but as is the case here, the context in which it was used

is what makes it unfriendly

@Zoeisonstrike in what context can calling s.o. stupid not be an insult?
Consider: "you're weird" -> "you're strange" vs. "you're an idiot" -> "you're a stupid person". "Stupid person" sounds unfriendly, even abusive to me. So I don't think it makes the argument you want it to.
Call me weird, I'd be ok with that (I'd probably agree). But call me an idiot or stupid person, I'd be offended.
But, I never claimed it not to be unfriendly, just not abusive. I think there is a huge difference.
Unfriendly is so subjective, I'd rather get rid of that flag, but that's another discussion.

I handled this comment. Declined the flag and deleted it.
Maybe the comment was not completely appropriate, but it was also posted in a moment of frustration by user who got downvoted without getting any kind of feedback and I thought that unfriendly unkind was a bit too much and that "No longer needed" would be a better option.
Maybe I handled it wrong. I will leave to other mods and community to judge whether my handling was appropriate or not.

An unfriendly/unkind flag marked as helpful leaves a record on the user, but it does not really affect them directly. Rather, it helps moderators understand whether that user has a tendency of making such remarks, at which point they ought to intervene, which is I believe flagging these incidents is important. I appreciate your transparency nonetheless.

Dalija, I strongly disagree with your reasoning. Having high tolerance personally is a great thing, but we should not impose that on the community. If someone is being rude, regardless of their state of mind and what they've experienced, they were being rude. There is no requirement for feedback when downvoting and I am sure you and I both downvoted without leaving a comment many many times. Putting all that aside, even with your reasoning, I'd have disputed the flag not decline. Cont'd...

@M-- It's not possible to dispute comment flags

... If it is not possible to dispute (I don't know if we can dispute comment flags), I will mark it as helpful. After all, the user who flagged the comment is right and we don't need to put ourselves in their shoes to justify their action.

I'd also apply the same logic to spam posts. Recently you handled one of my spam flags about an answer which was a link to the user's GitHub repository. That answer was purely there to promote (even with disclosing) as the question was already answered, and all that repo did was to modify the accepted answer ever so slightly so it was zoomed on a specific country (a plotting/mapping question). As you have deleted the answer, I did not follow up on it, but that was a good example for dispute (not decline).

@Zoeisonstrike you beat me to my "cont'd" comment :) I was trying to fit my 2nd and 3rd comment in one

'Moment of frustration' or does not make a comment any more or less abusive. Either the comment is abusive, based on the content in isolation, or not. If I were a moderator, I would have 100% marked that flag as helpful, not disputed (even if you could) nor declined.

I think you handled it wrong. :) The UU flag is precisely for comments like this. For when the user is frustrated and is not using friendly language. Once the user starts being verbally abusive and hurls insults directly at people then an abusive flag would be in order and possibly a mod message.

I hear you all. I will adjust my handling. Thanks for the feedback.

@M-- Spam flag  comes with a heavy penalty. I know it does not have to be applied, but posting a link to own GitHub repository on related question does not warrant a spam flag unless you see that user is really "spamming" that link across multiple answers.

@Ðаո Users care because declined flags can affect their ability to continue flagging. Furthermore, users hopefully don't want to improperly cast flags. A declined flag on a comment that is not deleted would probably have still warranted this question since it runs counter to consensus, but this situation was especially confusing because the flag was declined and yet the comment was deleted anyway.

I would have declined it too.  When I was a moderator, users that would eviscerate others but "technically" not be unkind would seem to be the ones that loved to custom flag folks saying one word out of line against them.  It felt like the rules lawyers were coming out to play back then. I see some similarities in this.

@GeorgeStocker Considering that the message in question was triggered by a downvote, that is the postcard message of taking downvotes too damn personally. I've said this way too many times now: if people cannot remain respectful in the face of adversity, that will inevitably hit them in the rear later on.

@E_net4 Except there is no direct feedback to the user except the comment being deleted. So they would notice that either way, but they will not get any upfront warning until they really cross the line. "If people cannot remain respectful in the face of adversity.." I can count number of people I know that can really do that using only one hand (maybe two if I try hard).

If the user is the one that tends to cross the line often enough, then such behavior will be noticed soon enough. And broader set of comments can be taken into account when deciding action. Not just the UU ones.

@DalijaPrasnikar Unfortunately, if there is one thing that the site will hardly ever manage to solve is set the right expectations, which includes not taking feedback for granted. I agree it's not ideal, but I don't see how removing and declining a flag handles the situation any better. It is also not just about seeing all comments posted  by a user, but knowing when it's high time to do something about that user. Flagging
comments at higher severity levels is what helps to determine this.

@E_net4 Agreed, which flag is used does not change much from that user perspective. I am not in position to comment on knowing when it is high time to handle users and whether noise level from frequent UU flags is getting in a way as I don't have that much experience, yet.

Of the three sentences, the first and last were personal insults.  U/U.  The second sentence was useful and appropriate, by requesting feedback.

Downvoted because I disagree with the way the flag was handled, but I really appreciate that you took the time to explain your thought process, so here's a virtual upvote to you Dalija. To me this is an example of very good moderation: Made a decision after have thought about it, did not hesitate to explain the reasoning, and being opened to discussion to improve own moderation. Thank you :)

@Laf Thank you. I have very good role models in former and current moderators. Moderation needs to be transparent and mistakes regardless of how they are made (intentional but wrong action, or accidentally wrong) are always possible.

@Technophile Even the second sentence was removable material, and a comment containing it in isolation should be flagged as no longer needed, as explained here.

@E_net4 I'll have to be honest, even if I am fully aware such comments rarely wield any result (and people expect the downvoted person is trying to react emotionally), I still like to write something like this when I do get downvoted on any SE site: " In the unlikely event that the downvoter would see this: what should I improve to make this question/answer useful?"

@Clockwork As explained in my previous comment however, please assume that it may just be deleted eventually. For what it's worth, the downvoter would have already left a comment if they really had wanted to do that.

Instead of flagging the comment and snitching, you could also reply to this comment and point out his misbehaviour. Most of the time, when the frustration has gone, the insight comes and the comment will be deleted.
And the term "weird" is really nowhere near as bad. His frustration is at least understandable.
But these are the "weird" times we live in. Most people are far too sensitive and turn a small thing, someone else's weak moment, into a tragedy. And the solution is usually not communication but censorship. What a shame.

"reply to this comment and point out his misbehaviour" We don't really want to start arguments in the comments. Flagging a comment is not "snitching" its just marking a comment that needs deletion. Deleting the comment is the simplest way to stop any potential arguments, code of conduct violations, etc.

This is exactly what one shouldn't do. It's escalating, and hardly ever have I seen anyone respond positively to something like this.

I've done my fair share of warning such users about the inappropriateness of certain actions on SO. The effects may vary, but are usually unproductive. Having received an e-mail accusing me of bashing new users for pointing out the lack of a minimal reproducible example, and one time also seeing a long defaming text file publicly on pastebin about me after warning someone of their misbehavior, it really makes me wonder whether my time is better spent doing things other than replying to unreasonable folks. The answer is yes, it is.

I think devops perspective is fair, especially that censorship has become the "solution" that's much worse than the problem.

@Deborah Meta-commentary does not belong on the main site in the first place. No one is stopping you from discussing about it constructively in an organized fashion, as what happens here on Meta, but the platform is not required to host those takes, much less in places where it does not belong.

@Deborah As to what the "solution" and/or "problem" really are, remember that there are always at least two sides of the story: a user who vented over a single downvote, and a volunteer who voted on a question and moved along without commenting. So we seemingly have 2 problems: that users do not always receive feedback when they were looking for it; and that users trying to help might waste their time or just be attacked in the process. In the former, feedback really isn't guaranteed under the policies established. Whereas in the latter, these cases are CoC violations.

No much more. There is also this persistent misunderstanding that quality voting and providing feedback are one and the same process. They're really not. Anyone can provide feedback at any time, including people who do not vote at all. Feedback about what is wrong can be given at score -50, 0 or +50, it makes no difference. Heck, someone who upvoted can still provide feedback on what can be improved. Its just not in any way linked. And then there is the most sad problem of all; giving feedback has a high risk of getting an outlandish response, so has become very unappealing to do.

i have to agree with the "censorship" quip, if nothing else, because it highlights that there is no corrective action available other than silencing a person. it would seem that this class of flags should come with a notification to the targeted user that there is a flag opened/completed so they can go review it and the commentary left by mods/community. this would help move any inflammatory content out of the Q&A and into the flag page, give the target user an opportunity to self-police, and also give the community a chance to help improve behavior --- rather than just rely on "censorship."

i feel like this is a salient point and site improvement opportunity that is being overlooked because the vast majority of users can't revision things as being any way other than the way they are, or otherwise disagree with other major points of @devops' feedback.

@wilson0x4d Your suggestion to notify users when their comments have been removed is not new, but it's not without its issues. Most of the comments are removed as no longer needed. Narrowing the comment flag notices down to U/U or H/B/A flags could be better, although there are implications which need to be considered with care.

@wilson0x4d But most important, let's not make it sound like opportunities for corrective action were completely overlooked. When enough flags for rudeness against a user's comments are marked as helpful, this automatically triggers a new flag against that user, which would call for a moderator to intervene, either by issuing a warning, or by warning and suspending the user.

And of course, on the overuse of the term "censorship", both in this answer and its comments, mandatory XKCD.

SO is (in my current understanding) intended to be a problem and solution, question and answer reference site useful to people trying to find relevant, useful information and/or trying to solve problems.  "Snitching" is not a concept that applies here.  If a post is incorrect, irrelevant, confusing, off-topic, rude, spam, etc. then it should get corrected or be cleaned up -- for the sake of all the other users of the site, who will have an easier time finding what they need.  Ideally, with courtesy by all involved.
