# Should a veil of anonymity have a say in how we flag offensive comments?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags, offensive

Today the following comment was spotted:

> To the downvoter. The least you can do is leave a f'ing comment as to why this answer deserved a downvote. Common decency and respect is what's lacking. Ignorance obviously is part of your every day life; good luck with that mofo.

In a single comment full of vitriol, the author managed to:

- shame the downvoter for not posting a comment, which is something we do not mandate nor wish users to be pressured into doing;
- suggested that the downvoter lacked decency and respect (out of an action that is well in their right to do without leaving a comment);
- attacked the downvoter's intelligence by calling them an ignorant;
- also called the downvoter a "mofo".

Even as an anonymous face in this interaction, should the downvoter revisit that page, they would certainly, to say the least, feel unjustly attacked. The subsequent comments posted by the same author were not very in line either, and at this point could even warrant an official warning from a moderator.

This was my rationale towards flagging the comment as Harassment/Abusive. However, *the flag was declined*, with the comment removed anyway.

Did the fact that the target was anonymous lead to the decision of declining the flag? Or was it a sporadic mistake? And for future reference, should the harassment/abusive flag never be used when there isn't a known name of the person to be referred to in that comment?

Comment: *"However, the flag was declined"* - on a comment calling someone an ignorant mother fer?, nice.

Comment: I don't think it was a mistake (as in a misclick). I also saw that comment and flagged it as "unfriendly or unkind" and was declined as well. I don't consider it _"harassment"_, but I certainly consider such a comment _"unfriendly"_. I hadn't realized the flag had been declined until I saw this question and I recognized the comment. I guess that that the comment is gone is the important thing in any case.

Comment: @yivi I too had that confirmed by another third party: a moderator declined the flag, no question. As my current reasoning sides with this being too out-of-line for just an unfriendly flag, this question serves to understand exactly what went through the process of handling the flag and what we should be doing in the future.

Comment: Whenever I'm in doubt, I reach for the NLN flags. Those are harmless and frictionless. I imagine the mod thought we should have done that in this case. I can't say I agree, but I can live with it.

Comment: If the flag, which ever one was used, got the comment examined by the mods, it was "helpful". NLN, R/A, Unkind? Don't matter, still don't belong.

Comment: @yivi I also fall back to NLN in case of doubt. Thing is though, quoted comment doesn't look like the case for _doubt_. The only doubt I have here is how come that moderator made a mistake handling such a blatantly offensive comment

Comment: I know @gnat. I wasn't in doubt, hence the "unfriendly" flag. If it wasn't a misclick, I simply disagree with the action. No biggie on that sense. My helpful-flag ratio went down below 99.3% again, which I don't like. But I'll make it somehow.

Comment: I'd feel a lot better if a mod also had a chat with the user in question. That comment goes beyond offensive, it's actively hostile and toxic (and incredibly oblivious).

Comment: @Ian Whatever happens between the user and the mods, if anything, is out of scope for the question. Let's not blow things out of proportion. This was simply about a declined flag, that's all. No need get enthusiastic about the witch-hunting.

Comment: There are a lot of us old-timers who still feel very strongly that you should not be able to downvote without leaving a comment. Strong enough to call someone a mofo? Maybe. Maybe...

Comment: @yivi The level of hostility and disproportionate nature of that response to what apparently triggered it, are concerning. Such apparently irrational anger can be a stress reaction to areas of life that are causing anxiety to the person who is lashing out. I appreciate it isn't the mods' duty to be personal counsellors, but reaching out to this user and simply asking if they are okay is what I would envision. (I understand what you interpreted my suggestion as, and am not offended; my past behaviour that led you to that conclusion is my responsibility. But I can't be an a--hole all the time!)

Comment: It's all good @Ian. Even if you are not offended, I apologize if I my response was harsher than necessary. I can be a bit tone-deaf myself at times. Peace.

Comment: @StackOverthrow I'm not sure three years qualifies as "old-timer." In my experience, most of the actual veterans of the site are strongly opposed to that suggestion.

Comment: Note to eventual readers of this diverging comment thread (which I believe could become a target of deletion): the author of the comment in question was suspended. Rest assured that the code of conduct applies to everyone all the same, and that this incident has been taken care of.

Comment: I am stressed out in my personal life, so I will be certain to comment the authors of megsDupe FAQ 'ignorant mofos' in future:)

Comment: I don't see that comment as shaming the downvoter.  Maybe it was an attempt to do that.  But all I see is a comment made by an OP who doesn't understand how the system works.

Comment: There is some irony that this question is the meta version of that comment (without the vitriol).  "To the moderator, the least you can do is explain why this flag was declined.  Clarification and consistency is what's lacking."

Comment: The greatest thing about comments is they can be ignored.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery You realize people have multiple accounts, right? And the majority you speak of was a minority that ganged up and bullied dissenters off the site.

Comment: @StackOverthrow please post your evidence for that claim, else some might think that you are trolling.  I could not possibly comment myself..

Comment: @StackOverthrow Please consider taking that subject to another question. But for what it's worth, the decision to never require feedback alongside a downvote was not a democratic one. The power user base (i.e. curators and moderators) holds the consensus that this is best for the site, and things won't change just because most users want something else.

Comment: @E_net4flagscomments: I used to explain my downvotes, but every time I did, I got into a "discussion" about it with the OP, so I don't do it anymore.  If people want to learn how to use the site properly, they don't need my help to do that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed, those who are in the category of "power users" such as ourselves eventually learn that. My point is that the decision to never require feedback with downvotes in this platform will not change, IMO rightly so, even if there happen to be more askers and answerers wanting that.

Comment: "_Common decency and respect is what's lacking_" What an irony ...

Comment: @John Just as an opposite data point: I definitely count as an old-timer (I’ve been here since the private beta) and I am *very* unhappy that the site does not enforce commenting for downvotes. I always thought, and still think, as strongly as ever, this is a mistake, and I don’t buy the justification at all. (Not that it matters, but the comment we’re discussing is obviously completely out of line regardless; calling out anonymous downvoting is fine, throwing insults isn’t).

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents: I hope that there was some escalation of warnings before the account was suspended. (a) I believe people should be responsible for what they say, (b) there are actually subcultures where such a comment is seen as combative but not overly hostile. One example is the little backwater town where I grew up. As I came to know larger scopes of the world I became more polite, but that process wasn't without friction. So I just hope there was something like "Stop it. If you don't stop we'll ban you" instead of just "You're banned" as the first response from moderators.

Comment: @KonradRudolph _"calling out anonymous downvoting is fine"_ [Except that it isn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393914)

Comment: @E_net4postsmemes As I implied in my comment, I simply don’t agree with this. It may (currently) be a majority opinion (but I’m not even convinced it is, outside of meta users) but it’s not a consensus and it’s not uncontroversial. Cody’s reply is an *opinion*, it’s not the law. And as mentioned by Cireo’s comment above, your question here is in principle doing the same thing so it seems *you* also disagree, or at least that your agreement is inconsistent.

Comment: @KonradRudolph even if just an opinion, it is one that nearly all moderators stand by. Even recently a moderator proposed that [a subset of these comments are 1-flag cleaned automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401007). In other words, one cannot expect such comments to stay for long. The rest of the comment that you edited in is a far-fetched extrapolation of what I said, and will be ignored.

Comment: @E_net4postsmemes You do you but you’re starting to sound a bit hypocritical.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Where exactly am I being hypocritical?

Comment: @E_net4postsmemes Like I said, this very question *is* the moral equivalent of the “why the downvote” comment. This isn’t a “far-fetched extrapolation”, it’s a clearly apparent fact. (And that’s totally fine, by the way.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, because that requires equating "explanations to downvotes" with "explanations to flag outcomes", an apples and oranges kind of comparison that does not check out.

Comment: @E_net4postsmemes It’s only an apples to oranges comparison if you assume a priori that every downvote is deserved (which seems to be the case, from reading your frankly bizarre reply on your last link). But that’s nonsense. Downvotes, like flags, are feedback/moderation tools which are occasionally misapplied or controversial, and should not be shielded from scrutiny. — Or, more interestingly, they *are correct*, and the downvoted person has a genuine desire to understand what they did wrong and improve. I wager that this is more frequently the case than not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, this isn't going anywhere, as clearly seen from your stance. Feel free to move away from my nonsense. Have a great day!

Comment: @StackOverthrow I consider myself somewhat of an old-timer (being a member for almost 10 years now), and I strongly oppose mandatory comments on downvotes (personally, I sometimes add an explanatory comment if it's not blatantly obvious why I downvote, but in the majority of occasions, I don't bother).

Comment: If there is anything "funny" in all this, it's that a response like the comment is likely why no downvote reason was given.

Answer (score 132):

That would be my fault.

I saw the rude/abusive flag, but when I read the comment I missed the "f'ing" and "mofo" so while the comment needed to go I didn't think it was rude.

Now that I read the comment again I see that I should have accepted the flag.

Sorry about that.

Comment: It's totally fine. But even without the "f'ing" and "mofo", wouldn't you say phrases like _"Common decency and respect is what's lacking. Ignorance obviously is part of your every day life"_ are unfriendly enough? Or were the expletives the only thing pushing the comment above the threshold?

Comment: Even without those two words I believe it would still count as rude... and even if not, unkind for sure

Comment: @yivi - In missing those words I got the tone of the comment wrong. I made a mistake.

Comment: @JohnDvorak - in retrospect I agree. However, I can't change how I processed the flag.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I came without my pitchfork anyway. :)

Comment: @yivi I wasn't lucky enough to realize that I wouldn't need *my* pitchfork. Now I have to drag it all the way back.

Comment: Hey, cut the new mods some slack! ChrisF has only been doing this since... wait... :-)

Comment: Thank you! I wish we had a best practices page on SO: this answer is an example of how to admit a mistake well (promptly, correctly, and with just the right amount of explanation).

Comment: Keep in mind they spend all day staring at hundreds of comments like this, a mistake once in a while is bound to happen. We've all had that moment where we'd just been doing something for too long, our eyes glaze over, and we need a break, right? :p

Comment: If you didn't think the comment was rude, why did you think it needed to go? Simultaneously declining the flag, and deleting the comment, just seems completely contradictory to me, mistake or not.

Comment: There's a difference between rude and unfriendly. Unfriendly comment still gets the axe, but the poster generally doesn't (unless they've built up a history).

Answer (score 68):

That flag should not have been declined.

Even under the now long gone Be Nice policy that comment was off-limits. With the new Code of Conduct the rules got more strict and clear: We don't want that kind of content on our site, not in a question, answer or comment.

It is not in the interest of this community that users who think it is okay to post that kind of attacks are given a warning or a second chance or are shielded for consequences of red flags.

It is in the interest of this community that users who raise rude/abusive flags for posts that violate the CoC are taken seriously. The flagger should not have any backlash for faithfully flagging content that is in clear breach of the Code of Conduct.

I'm not sure if the system allows for fixing comment flags after the fact. That would be the preferred outcome here. I assume the mod who clicked the buttons did so in error. If not, I think we, as a community, need to establish clear guidance by example for the mod team that these kind of comments are red flaggable and that raised flags on these kind of comments need to be marked helpful without exceptions.

Comment: "It is not in the interest of this community that users who think it is okay to post that kind of attacks are given a warning [or] a second chance" - disagree. Sometimes people do learn.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Alas, although anecdotal, an attempt at instructing the author of this particular comment did not go well. It's not uncommon (I'd dare say it's more common) for a poster of offensive comments to follow up with more heated comments than to learn the lesson.

Comment: The last sentences of this answer are the ones which resonate the most. I don't think there's a way to "repair" comment flags, and I could shrug off a few declined flags much easier than post flags, especially since there is no automatic penalty for flagging too many declined flags. On the other hand, I would really appreciate a consensus and/or guideline on which option to choose for this kind of comment.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I could probably word that better but what I try to explain is that not handling those comments might give the impressions that you can get away once or twice with such comments. Yes, people learn, in this case that needs to be instant learning by coming down hard. Not by some handwaving for the first offense.

Comment: _"Even under the now long gone Be Nice policy"_ Wait... there is no more "Be nice" policy !?

Comment: @Pac0 what can I say. It wasn't enough to "Be Nice". We needed a Code of Conduct. That replaced being nice: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review

Comment: @rene I would be forthcoming with the user, society and the internet in general are an aggressive place. Joining a forum is also an opportunity of personal growth, if the user understands that language isn't acceptable without getting an outright account nuke (or something overly severe) he'll be given a chance to adjust. I'd point out the forms of passive-aggressive bigotry that while not flaggable are equally as aggressive or even worst than just swearing and a straight insult. We are also not given the full context of provocations that may have triggered that reaction.

Comment: @bad_coder Stack Overflow is not a forum, so there shouldn't be too much discussion in comment that isn't related to the post. As for the rest: I have tried many times to explain and to reason with user, but most times that made me a target. It's best to flag and move on. That comment was also pretty tame, I've seen much worse!

Comment: No context would have justified the comment above, @bad_coder. And where one may see an opportunity of self growth, it unfortunately too often becomes grounds for pointless back and forth or backlash. The lesson learned: [avoid discussions caused by a downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312634/1233251).